# how to echo a custom taxonomy term from an array of term

Tags: taxonomy

I have custom post type `products` & custom taxonomy `product_type` which has many terms & the `products` can have multiple `product_type`  terms assigned to it Ex. `A Samsung TV Model` post has product_type as `New arrivals` , `featured` & `tv` .
I am trying to output only the specific custom taxonomy term [hyperlink] from an array on a single `products` post :-

```
if( has_term( array( 'laptop', 'TV', 'phone', 'tablet' ), 'product_type' ) ) :
  // Do stuff here
else :
  // DONT SHOW ANYTHING
endif;
?>
```

entering a text instead of `// Do stuff here` in above code works. I want to echo the actual tax term from that array. Tried `echo $term;` , `echo get_the_term();` but it doesnt work. How do i output the custom term from this array ?

Comment: Please share your full query, only sharing a tiny portion of it doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 0):

You're checking if a `product_type` has a term using `has_term()`. Now you need to actually get the terms using `get_terms()`. That function can technically return from 1 to 4 terms. If more than one of the terms is set, you'll need to pick one. In the following code, I chose the first since there's guaranteed to be at least one term.

```
if( has_term( [ 'laptop', 'TV', 'phone', 'tablet' ], 'product_type' ) ) {
  //* Get the terms
  $terms = get_terms( [
    'taxonomy' => 'product_type',
    'slug'     => [ 'laptop', 'TV', 'phone', 'tablet' ],
  ] );
  //* There could still be up to 4 terms, so use the first
  echo $terms[0]->name;
}
```

Comment: thanks Nathan its works ,so we had to define the `$terms`  cud tell   abt this line -  `//* There could still be up to 4 terms, so use the first`  what it means ? does it mean the code will not work if suppose we have 5 or 6 terms in that square bracket ? coz i find this weird prob that if i enter 5 terms , it keeps on displaying the wrong term

Comment: Also is there a way we could hyperlink the term as my intial question was abt the term which wud be clickable i.e. using something like $term->slug  ?

Comment: Nathan can u correct the code ? i think the prob is that `[0]`  Wrong term gets displayed

Comment: `$term[0]` displays the 1st term from `get_terms` which actually checks for all the terms & not the terms that are attached to the current post. That `has_term` function only for conditional purpose seems of no help in current code because the `get_term` doesnt behave according to it...